# Viewcontroller scene loading delay

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, swift2, xcode7

I have created one app with some screens. Everything is working. Now my issue is when I load my application it is showing with different places after few seconds it set with the constraints.

I am using some label and buttons in this scene and set text from the viewController.swift file. First showing without text after loading it showing text.

I am also using `wAny and hAny`.

All the other viewControllers working fine. But only first viewController showing these issues.

Can someone please tell me what are the details i need to provide here.

Comment: Please provide more details, screenshots for example.

Comment: What screenshot do you want?

Comment: try putting up screenshots of the issue. What happens when you run the app. Also try putting up a screen shot of how you actually want it to be displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed my issue. But don't know the reason why it is happening. I did it like

1. Click ViewController scene
2. Open show the identity Inspector
3. Remove Storyboard ID
4. Add the StoryBoard ID

Now my app loading without any delay. Completely no idea why it is happening.

My screen Shot

[image: Remove like this].

Add add back like this  [image: After add again]